# Allowing only a maximum integer input and no alphabets in python

Tags: python, string, input, integer

I am new in python and I am supposed to create a game where the input can only be in range of 1 and 3. (player 1, 2 , 3) and the output should be error if user input more than 3 or error if it is in string.

```
def makeTurn(player0):

    ChoosePlayer= (raw_input ("Who do you want to ask? (1-3)"))

    if ChoosePlayer > 4:
        print "Sorry! Error! Please Try Again!"
        ChoosePlayer= (raw_input("Who do you want to ask? (1-3)"))

    if ChoosePlayer.isdigit()== False:
        print "Sorry! Integers Only"
        ChoosePlayer = (raw_input("Who do you want to ask? (1-3)"))
    else:
        print "player 0 has chosen player " + ChoosePlayer + "!"
        ChooseCard= raw_input("What rank are you seeking from player " + ChoosePlayer +"?")
```

I was doing it like this but the problem is that it seems like there is a problem with my code. if the input is 1, it still says "error please try again"  im so confused!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`raw_input` returns a string. Thus, you're trying to do `"1" > 4`. You need to convert it to an integer by using [`int`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int)

If you want to catch whether the input is a number, do:

```
while True:
    try:
        ChoosePlayer = int(raw_input(...))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print ("Numbers only please!")
```

Just note that now it's an integer, your concatenation below will fail. Here, you should use [`.format()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)

```
 print "player 0 has chosen player {}!".format(ChoosePlayer)
```

Comment: Yes, but in order to do `int(raw_input(…`, you'd need to wrap it up in a try/catch to handle `ValueError`s

Comment: @ArgiriKotsaris No. Although that will work for numbers, it will break if a string is inputted.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Added that. Sorry for lateness, I'm on my phone :p

Comment: @Haidro: I actually was about to ask whether you were on a mobile device. The usage of `Raw_input` was a dead giveaway :P

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to convert ChoosePlayer to an int, like:

```
ChoosePlayerInt = int(ChoosePlayer)
```

Otherwise, at least with pypy 1.9, ChoosePlayer comes back as a unicode object.

Answer (score -1):

You have to cast your value to int using method [`int()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int):

```
 def makeTurn(player0):
    ChoosePlayer= (raw_input ("Who do you want to ask? (1-3)"))

    if int(ChoosePlayer) not in  [1,2,3]:
        print "Sorry! Error! Please Try Again!"
        ChoosePlayer= (raw_input("Who do you want to ask? (1-3)"))

    if ChoosePlayer.isdigit()== False:
        print "Sorry! Integers Only"
        ChoosePlayer = (raw_input("Who do you want to ask? (1-3)"))
    else:
        print "player 0 has chosen player " + ChoosePlayer + "!"
        ChooseCard= raw_input("What rank are you seeking from player " + ChoosePlayer +"?")
```